# Application Gateway Broken Chain SSL Testing

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

The scenario is to test Broken Chain certificate. I have a Broken Chain Certificate by removing Intermediate Certificate(merged Server, Issuing, Intermediate and Root information into single .pem file, removed Intermediate information from it and converted it to .pfx) and uploaded it to Application Gateway. But when I am hitting the URL in browser or running OpenSSL show cert command, I am unable to see Broken Chain information. Had restarted Application Gateway too.

I am sure it is not getting downloaded from my Certificate Authority AIA folder as I have renamed it.

Does Application Gateway caches the certificate information by downloading it from Certificate Authority AIA folder and keeps on using the same information?

Comment: I got my query answered on MS forum and might be helpful for others for facing similar issue.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c57d742a-d569-4a3c-811e-8a9e39852bc1/application-gateway-broken-chain-ssl-testing?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to open port `80` in outbound. a server will communicate with intermediate CA to validate the certificate